# So many volatility models. Any comparisons of them?

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, garch, econometrics

Are there any papers that make an explicit contrast/comparison of the following (or other) vol models in terms of the suitability for addressing some empirical problem?

- Wavelet multiresolution volatility
- EWMA
- GARCH family
- range volatility
- derivative implied volatility, models from stochastic finance. SABR etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may want to first broadly categorize volatility models before comparing between them within each class, it does not make sense to compare standard deviation models with an implied vol model.

I would broadly classify as follows:

- Historical realized volatility: Those include standard deviation (sum of squared deviations), realized range volatility models, and essentially anything that is based on past price and return data. Such models strictly deal with past data points and do not bother to make any sort of prediction.
- Implied volatility models: Those lead to volatility measures that are the other side of the coin of derivative prices, whereas the implied vol model functions as translation tool. Part of that categorization is the SABR model and essentially most all stochastic models that implement different sorts of Brownian Motion "drivers".
- Volatility forecasting models generally utilize past data, contrary to implied volatility models, in order to make predictions about future volatility dynamics and levels. Most Garch volatility models fall under this category.
- A sub-category deals with intra-day volatility models such as Pearson or Garman-Klass.

I understand that my answer does not compare each individual volatility model but I believe, or hope, it helps to broadly compare and classify different models.

Comment: @Jase: adding to Matt Wolf excellent answer I would say that any model has at least one purpose, so comparing models should primarily take this into account. Best regards.

Comment: Very nice answer, but could you please elaborate on "it does not make sense to compare standard deviation models with an implied vol model." Why doesn't this make sense?

Comment: @Jase, because those are different tools aiming to target entirely different questions. (Sample) standard deviation measures variation in past price/return data whereas implied volatility expresses expectations of future asset/asset return variation.

Comment: What about comparing forecasts from a realized model to the implied vol?

Comment: They are not comparable either. Forecasts of realized data fall into the same category as Garch models (though Garch models additionally incorporate Brownian Motion). Implied volatility models do not deal with realized pricing data but current prices and expected values.

Comment: So you're saying that we can't compare forecasts from realized models and implied vol because realized models are based on historical prices and implied models deal with current prices? While this is true I'm still not clear why this means that we can't compare the two meaningfully.

Comment: @Jase, you can compare anything, whether you derive meaningful conclusions from your comparison is a different issue. I do not believe one derives value from comparing volatility models that are almost entirely based on historical prices with a model that captures market expectations of future price levels and/or variation. One is used to assess past price return variation, the other to price contracts with future contingent payoffs.

Comment: +1 -- I wish I had seen this sooner.  Clear and thoughtful

Comment: yeah, the question is too broad... basically, 'volatility' can fall into two classes
1) the pricing models (stoch-vol, replication-models, short-rate etc
2) portfolio-based models, such as GARCH, EWMA etc

Question should distinguish between the two as they are used differently.